# Convergence of iterative solution of nonlinear system

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-analysis

I need to solve the following system of nonlinear equations
$$A(x)x = B\, , \hspace{12mm} (1)$$
where $x, B \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Here $A$ is an $n \times n$ tridiagonal matrix with $x$-dependent diagonal elements,
$$ A_{ii}(x) = \frac{c_i}{\|x\|} + d_i \hspace{8mm} \mathrm{with} \hspace{3mm} c_i, \hspace{0.5mm} d_i \in \mathbb{R} \hspace{8mm} \mathrm{and}  \hspace{8mm} \|x\| =(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)^{1/2} \, ,$$
but whose other elements do not depend on $x$.

To this end I devised the following method. Pick a random $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and iteratively solve
$$A(x_j)x_{j+1} = B \, , \hspace{12mm} (2)$$
for $x_{j+1}$ until $\| x_{j+1} - x_j \|$ is below an acceptable threshold. Letting $x$ denote an exact solution to eq. (1) above, and defining error vectors as $x_j = x + \epsilon_j$, one observes roughly quadratic convergence $\| \epsilon_{j+1} \| \sim \mathcal{O}(\| \epsilon_j \|^2)$ in numerical experiments. However, plugging $x_j = x + \epsilon_j$ and $x_{j+1} = x + \epsilon_{j+1}$ into eq. (2) above and Taylor expanding the entries on the diagonal of $A$, one finds
$$\epsilon_{j+1} = \frac{\epsilon_j \cdot x}{\| x \|^3} A(x_j)^{-1} \mathrm{diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_n) x \, .$$
This does not readily explain the observed convergence. In practice, the quantity $A(x_j)^{-1} \mathrm{diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ is numerically small as computed through the iterations, but it is not obvious (at least to me) why this should be the case. Convergence is almost as fast for non-tridiagonal matrices $A(x)$. (Incidentally, the equation system (1) arises from finite-difference methods applied to a second-order nonlinear ODE.)

My questions are now:

1. Can anyone on this forum explain the experimentally observed quadratic convergence $\| \epsilon_{j+1} \| \sim \mathcal{O}(\| \epsilon_j \|^2)$?
2. Is the approach in eq. (2) a standard approach and have a name?

Answer (score 1):

So, you are running a fixed point iteration of the form $x^{(j+1)}= G(x^{(j)})$, with $G(x) = (A(x))^{-1}B$. Assuming $z$ is the fixed point,Taylor expansion gives you
$$
G(x^{(n)}) = G(z)+J_G(z)(x^{(n)}-z)+ O(\|x^{(n)}-z\|^2)
$$
or,
$$
x^{(n+1)}-z = J_G(z)(x^{(n)}-z)+O(\|x^{(n)}-z\|^2).
$$

If you are observing quadratic convergence, this must be explained by having $J_G(z)=0$. Checking this equality would do the trick.

---

$J_G$ stands for the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In practice one observes that $J_G(z)$ isn't zero, but numerically small, with the absolute values of the entries typically 100 to 1000 times smaller than the entries of A or the fixed point z. Is there any way of understanding this?

Comment: One more question: is there any theory/systematic approach other than a brute-force grid search of understanding which regions of entries of A and B that lead to convergence of the fixed-pont iteration vs. regions where convergence fails?

Comment: If $J_g(z)\ne 0$ the convergence isn't really quadratic, it just looks that way in the "normal" range of accuracy goals. Did you try to directly estimate the order of convergence, based on  "exact" solutions obtained with a very large number of iterations?

Comment: Indeed, the convergence isn't strictly speaking quadratic in the sense that $J_G(z) =0$. However, the entries of $J_G(z)$ tend to be much smaller than those of $A$. Is there some reason expect this? (In practice, I iterate until $\| x_j \| - \| x_{j+1} \|$ gets below some threshold. Unfortunately, convergence is less reliable in regions of $A_{ij}$ values of practical interest.)